# Conditions for Convergence of Newton's method

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

My professor said that if we have a twice continuously differentiable real function $f$ in an interval $[a,b]$ such that:

1. $f(a)f(b)<0$
2. $f'$ and $f''$ don't change signs and $f'$ does not vanish

If $f(a)f''(a)>0$ or $f(b)f''(b)>0$ then starting at $x_0=a$ or $x_0=b$ respectively then Newton's method converges.

I suspect this is false, but I can't come up with a counterexample.

Could anyone find one?

Comment: Some proof ideas and applications can be found using in [these search results](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=newton+tangent+root+interval+convergence)

Answer (score 1):

This is corrct : it is Darboux theorem (have a look [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/NAM_1869_2_8__17_0.pdf) for the original paper).

Have another one [here](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Egelineau/devagreg/Theoreme_Darboux.pdf) (it is in French but it is easy to read).

It is very important for numerical analysis and computing.